# How can I start two asynchronous threads which join to common execution once both are complete?

Tags: android, asynchronous

I'm looking for a design pattern or approach for the following scenario.  I wish to kick off two separate background threads for data retrieval from different sources.  I then want one method (on the UI thread) to be called once both background threads have completed their work.  As the data from the two sources must be combined to be useful, I must wait until both have finished retrieving before manipulating the data.  How can I achieve this on the Android platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** My first version has been bothering me, and I didn't like the necessary added boolean with it, so here's another version. Call it with `this` from `onPostExecute` of each added task.

```
ArrayList<AsyncTask> tasks;

public void doStuffWhenDone(AsyncTask finishedTask)
{
    tasks.remove(finishedTask);
    if(tasks.size() > 0)
        return;

    ... do stuff
}
```

I'll keep the older one up also, since they both work, but I think the above is much cleaner. Now to go tidy up one of my earlier projects.

```
ArrayList<AsyncTask> tasks;
boolean hasBeenDone = false;

public void doStuffWhenDone()
{
    for(int i=0;i<tasks.size();i++)
        if(hasBeenDone || (tasks.get(i).getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))
            return;

    hasBeenDone = true;
    ... do stuff
}
```

It's easily extendable to however many tasks you have, and there's no need for a thread to handle the threads. Just call the method at the end of each task. If it's not the last one done, nothing happens.

Edit: Good point, but I don't think it needs to be atomic. Since both AsyncTasks' `onPostExecute` methods run on the UI thread, they'll be called one after the other.

Comment: Although, now that I think about it, I'm fairly certain its possible for both tasks to finish at the same time (well, one machine instruction after the other) and therefore cause the 'do stuff' code to get executed twice.  Maybe needs combined with an atomic boolean to keep track of whether or not the 'do stuff' code has been executed.

Comment: Better solution added. This is what happens when I can't sleep.

Comment: lol, looks even better.  Only query I might have is if it wouldn't make sense to make doStuffWhenDone() synchronized as couldn't both async threads execute the ``tasks.remove(..)`` before either goes through the if statement yielding dual execution of the ``do stuff`` code?

Comment: Only if it's called from `doInBackground` instead of `onPostExecute` like it should be. If called correctly, they'll both be run on the UI thread, sequentially. You could add it in as a fail-safe, but only to protect from programmer errors, not execution ones.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [CountDownLatch](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), like this:

```
CountDownLatch barrier = new CountDownLatch(2); // init with count=2
startWorkerThread1(barrier);
startWorkerThread2(barrier);
barrier.await(); // it will wait here until the count is zero
doStuffWithTheResult();
```

when a worker thread finishes, call **barrier.countDown()** from it.

Comment: You can implement the worker threads any way you like - with the AsyncTasks, or as a plain Thread. Maybe AsyncTasks are better, because they use a thread pool so the initialization should be faster.

Comment: Doesn't `await()` block the calling thread? Unless you called this from yet another thread(making 3 in addition to the UI), the UI would be blocked, which isn't normally desired.

Comment: You're right, third thread is required. AsyncTask would fit nicely for this job - in "doInBackground()" barrier.await() would be called and then some stuff done with the result, in "onPostExecute(Result)" the UI would be refreshed.

Comment: Thanks, hadn't heard of this one before

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AsyncTask` and an `int` to know if both jobs are finished...